# Ember.js frontend javascript execution after Ember initialized

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I am using a jQuery plugin that makes the frontend of my website function correctly. Since Ember initializes after the plugin my website doesn't work. The plugin initializes when a secondary configuration script executes. I put this script in a function on the client-side page. The plugin is referenced in the head. The script is in the body inside of Handlebars (at the bottom so Handlebars still works). How would I execute my function after Ember initializes.

*EX:*

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript src="plugin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/handlebars>
        <!--Website-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initializeMyPlugin(){
                // Plugin Configuration
                // I believe this needs to be executed after Ember initializes
            }
        </script>
    </script>
    <!--Ember File References-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would probably be to wrap your plugin inside a component and execute the function inside `didInsertElement`

Something like:

```
App.SomeComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    initializeMyPlugin();
  }
});
```

I suggest watching [this](http://eviltrout.com/2014/06/03/jquery-component.html) by Evil Trout to get many more details about wrapping a jQuery plugin in your component

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response (and the fact that I am rather new to Ember) but how do I use components?